# File Upload parsing issue on Joomla form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, joomla

Having issues with resume upload parsing page:

http://ablcareers-dev.cloudaccess.host/search-abl-jobs/resume/013947 as an example

When a user clicks to upload their resume, and selects CONFIRM INFO, the page refreshes after a couple of seconds and it appears as if no data has been processed.

Code is below, simple file upload and script. Working with Joomla.

```
<form class="uk-form"  name="frmMain" method="post" id="frmMain" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="jobId" value="<?= $this->jobID ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?= $this->email ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="resume" />
    <input class="form-control  uk-form-large uk-width-7-10" id="filResume1" type="file" name="filResume1" />
    <button class="uk-button-primary submit uk-button" >Confirm Info</button>
    <label class="error" for="filResume1"></label>
    <button class="noresume uk-button uk-button-primary" >I  don't have a resume</button>
    <p style="font-size:12px">No Resume? No Problem you can still apply manually</p>
    <p id="spProcessing"></p>
 </form>

<script>
    jQuery('.submit').click(function() {
        jQuery('#spProcessing').text('Processing resume ............... ');
        jQuery('#frmMain').submit();
    });
    jQuery('.noresume').click(function() {
        jQuery('#frmMain').submit();
    });
 </script>
```

There are no errors in the console, and I cannot figure out what may be the cause of the issue.

Would the PHP / MySQL version possibly affect tthe functionality of this?

```
function uploadParseResume(){
    $applicantId = $this->sendRequest(self::$serviceUrl ."/applicant");
    if ($applicantId === false)
        return false;

    $applicantId = str_replace('"', "", $applicantId);
    $resume1= $_FILES['filResume1']['tmp_name'];
    $resume2= $_FILES['filResume2']['tmp_name'];
    $resume3= $_FILES['filResume3']['tmp_name'];
    $resume4= $_FILES['filResume4']['tmp_name'];
    $resume5= $_FILES['filResume5']['tmp_name'];

    $tmpDir = dirname($_FILES['filResume1']['tmp_name']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $target = $tmpDir . $_FILES["filResume1"]["name"];

    $post = array();

    if($resume1!=''){
        $file_name_with_full_path = realpath($target);
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['filResume1']['tmp_name'], $target);
        $post = array(
            'resume_name' => '@'.$file_name_with_full_path,
            'file_contents[0]'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path
        );

    }
    if($resume2!=''){
        $target2 = $tmpDir. $_FILES["filResume2"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['filResume2']['tmp_name'], $target2);
        array_push($post,'@'.realpath($target2),'file_contents[1]');
    }

    if($resume3!=''){
        $target3 = $tmpDir. $_FILES["filResume3"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['filResume3']['tmp_name'], $target3);
        array_push($post,'@'.realpath($target3),'file_contents[2]');
    }

    if($resume4!=''){
        $target4 = $tmpDir. $_FILES["filResume4"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['filResume4']['tmp_name'], $target4);
        array_push($post,'@'.realpath($target4),'file_contents[3]');
    }

    if($resume5!=''){
        $target5 = $tmpDir. $_FILES["filResume5"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['filResume5']['tmp_name'], $target5);
        array_push($post,'@'.realpath($target5),'file_contents[4]');
    }

    $result ="";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::$serviceUrl . "/file/upload/?id=".$applicantId);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . self::$apiKey));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result  === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch) . '   ' . curl_errno($ch) . 
   '<br>';
    }


    curl_close($ch);
    $info = "";
    $workHistory = "";
    $applicantId = "";

    $firstName ="";
    $lastName = "";
    $phone = "";
    $mobile = "";
    $street = "";
    $city = "";
    $suite = "";
    $postalCode = "";
    $positionDesired = "";
    $website = "";
    $companyName1 ="";
    $startDate1 = "";
    $endDate1 = "";
    $title1 = "";
    $reason1 = "";
    $super1 = "";
    $phone1 = "";
    $payRate1 = "";
    $desc1 = "";    
    $companyName2 ="";
    $startDate2 = "";
    $endDate2 = "";
    $title2 = "";
    $reason2 = "";
    $super2 = "";
    $phone2 = "";
    $payRate2 = "";
    $desc2 = "";
    $companyName3 ="";
    $startDate3 = "";
    $endDate3 = "";
    $title3 = "";
    $reason3 = "";
    $super3 = "";
    $phone3 = "";
    $payRate3 = "";
    $desc3 = "";



    if($result!="")
    {

        $obj = json_decode($result);
        $info = $obj->{'info'};
        $applicantId = $info->{'applicantId'};
        $firstName = $info->{'firstName'};
        $lastName = $info->{'lastName'};
        $phone = $info->{'phone'};
        $mobile = $info->{'CellPhone'};
        $street = $info->{'street'};
        $city = $info->{'city'};
        $suite = $info->{'suite'};
        $postalCode = $info->{'postalCode'};
        $positionDesired = $info->{'positionDesired'};
        $website = $info->{'website'};
        $workHistory = $info->{'workHistory'};
        $companyName1 = $workHistory->{'companyName1'};
        $startDate1 = $workHistory->{'startDate1'};
        $endDate1 = $workHistory->{'endDate1'};
        $title1 = $workHistory->{'title1'};
        $reason1 = $workHistory->{'reason1'};
        $super1 = $workHistory->{'super1'};
        $phone1 = $workHistory->{'phone1'};
        $payRate1 = $workHistory->{'payRate1'};
        $desc1 = $workHistory->{'desc1'};
        $companyName2 = $workHistory->{'companyName2'};
        $startDate2 = $workHistory->{'startDate2'};
        $endDate2 = $workHistory->{'endDate2'};
        $title2 = $workHistory->{'title2'};
        $reason2 = $workHistory->{'reason2'};
        $super2 = $workHistory->{'super2'};
        $phone2 = $workHistory->{'phone2'};
        $payRate2 = $workHistory->{'payRate2'};
        $desc2 = $workHistory->{'desc2'};
        $companyName3 = $workHistory->{'companyName3'};
        $startDate3 = $workHistory->{'startDate3'};
        $endDate3 = $workHistory->{'endDate3'};
        $title3 = $workHistory->{'title3'};
        $reason3 = $workHistory->{'reason3'};
        $super3 = $workHistory->{'super3'};
        $phone3 = $workHistory->{'phone3'};
        $payRate3 = $workHistory->{'payRate3'};
        $desc3 = $workHistory->{'desc3'};

    }
    session_start();
//  $_SESSION['applicantId'] = $applicantId;
    $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
    $_SESSION['responsecode'] = $responsecode;
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = $mobile;
    $_SESSION['street'] = $street;
    $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
    $_SESSION['postalCode'] = $postalCode;
    $_SESSION['companyName1'] = $companyName1;
    $_SESSION['startDate1'] = $startDate1;
    $_SESSION['endDate1'] = $endDate1;
    $_SESSION['title1'] = $title1;
    $_SESSION['reason1'] = $reason1;
    $_SESSION['super1'] = $super1;
    $_SESSION['phone1'] = $phone1;
    $_SESSION['payRate1'] = $payRate1;
    $_SESSION['desc1'] = $desc1;
    $_SESSION['companyName2'] = $companyName2;
    $_SESSION['startDate2'] = $startDate2;
    $_SESSION['endDate2'] = $endDate2;
    $_SESSION['title2'] = $title2;
    $_SESSION['reason2'] = $reason2;
    $_SESSION['super2'] = $super2;
    $_SESSION['phone2'] = $phone2;
    $_SESSION['payRate2'] = $payRate2;
    $_SESSION['desc2'] = $desc2;
    $_SESSION['companyName3'] = $companyName3;
    $_SESSION['startDate3'] = $startDate3;
    $_SESSION['endDate3'] = $endDate3;
    $_SESSION['title3'] = $title3;
    $_SESSION['reason3'] = $reason3;
    $_SESSION['super3'] = $super3;
    $_SESSION['phone3'] = $phone3;
    $_SESSION['payRate3'] = $payRate3;
    $_SESSION['desc3'] = $desc3;
//  echo '<pre>';
//  print_r($obj);
//  echo $companyName1;
//  echo $street;
//  echo '</pre>';  

    return $applicantId;
```

Any insight would be helpful,

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the PHP code that handles the file / data once it reaches the server?

Comment: I included the resume parsing PHP function in the original post now. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked if joomla handles the files in a other way ?

Comment: The process should be working just fine. We are using two different websites that have the same component running in principle, with some elements being different. Resume upload and parsing is the same, and was working before. I have considered the possibility of hosting (PHP/MySQL version and Joomla version) to be the culprit of this not working, but unable to recreate the environment because of poor technical support from the host. 

In the meantime, I figured popping the question up to see if anyone would have any ideas why this may not be working.

Comment: I'd suggest using the core Joomla form classes. These are well developed and extremely safe.   If it's just one form you can just use custom fields in an article.  I'd also suggest that you visit the Joomla stack exchange site [joomla.se] for detailed advice.

Comment: Where is the 'action' attribute in form?